# Passing additional data to event listeners in Javascript

Tags: javascript, single-page-application

Say I have two views:

1. Gallery: shows a list of sketches, can be accessed by `www.mywebsite.com/#gallery`
2. Sketch: shows a single sketch, can be accessed by `www.mywebsite.com/#sketch/:id`

Every time a user clicks on a sketch in the gallery, I want to go to the Sketch view passing in the sketch that was clicked.

How can I make this work?

I already tried using `CustomEvent`s:

```js
  onSketchClick = () => {
    const event = new CustomEvent('hashchange')

    event.additionalData = {
      sketchElement: this.element
    }

    window.dispatchEvent(event)
  }
```

It works great, but the URL doesn't change when the sketch is clicked.

I could simply add

`window.location.hash = '#sketch/${this.id}'`

inside `onSketchClick` but that would trigger the `hashchange` event listener twice.

Is there any way I can send data without using `CustomEvent`s?

Comment: You tagged this as single-page-application. Are you using client side routing?

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 hey, that's right

Comment: I strongly advise against this approach. Extract the ID from the URL and fetch the data when the hash changes. Otherwise users can bookmark and share broken links an, even worse, you risk your application becoming a complex, highly stateful mess filled with implicit assumptions and very hard to maintain.

Comment: @AluanHaddad the Sketch view checks if a sketch was sent to it, otherwise it will fetch from the URL. is it then still an issue?

Comment: @kibe at least you've provided for the contingency and that definitely solves the bookmarking and sharing problem but it does make debugging and app structure more complicated. It may be worth doing for slow data sources, but I would submit that creating your own client-side router is non-trivial and that passing data in navigation events is something to add when you've ironed everything else out, if ever.